# Products are not inserted in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

mysqli_select_db($con,'go');

if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
    $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
    $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
    if($product_title==''  OR $product_keywords==''){
        echo "<script> alert('please field all the fields!')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $insert_query = "insert into 
     products(product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_keywords,product_image) values('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_keywords','$product_image')";

        move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"images/{$product_image}");
        if(mysqli_query($con,$insert_query)){
            echo "<script>alert('Data inserted into table')</script>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should read-up on sql injection.

Comment: And what error are you receiving when you try to execute your query? I don't see any code there that would show you the error, so that's probably a good place to start.

Comment: your code seems fine. what error you're getting?

Comment: @MayankVadiya Good thing you posted it as a comment, it would probably earn you a lot of down-votes :-)

Comment: sir, i am not getting any php error.

Comment: i am getting undefined variable after changing the sql like this '".$product_cat."'

Comment: i am getting undefined veriable when i put like this '".$product_cat."'

Comment: First of you really need to learn how to ask a question here. Secondly you need to post both codes your form code and the processing code which you have posted. Also you need to tell exactly what problem you're facing there's very little information in your question to help us solve it. Also you're getting in to very bad habits as @jeroen said you need read on sql injection and using prepare statements.

Comment: Suggest you just remove everything and `echo` all the `$_POST` variables to make sure all of them are getting submitted to the above process page.